# Converting a Maya scene to JavaScript or WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, maya

I have some time and I'd like to convert a Maya scene to WebGL or render it to a canvas if possible without WebGL.  The model is of a desk lamp consisting of primitives and meshes, I've parented parts to the joints instead of binding them to the skeleton and now I want to use a JS library or WebGL to render, then animate with mouse movement and/or touch event.  If I can get the model onto a canvas, or into a WebGL enabled application while conserving the parented relationships, I could then write a few functions to bind joint rotation to mouse movements, I just need a little help with actually exporting and importing my Maya scene while conserving relationships.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) WebGL library for that. They have exporters from 3D models to JSON written in python [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters).

For example you can try to export your model in `obj` and then convert it using  [convert_obj_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/obj/convert_obj_three.py).

Then you can load your model into canvas using `THREE.JSONLoader` method. There is a lot of examples on internet.

Comment: Thanks, I see there's an exporter for Blender and 3DMax as well.  I was under the impression rendering complex shapes could only be done with WebGL, but it looks like Three.js use does use WebGL.

Comment: Yeah, Three.js has 2d and WebGL renderers.

Answer (score 1):

If your scene is already in Maya then www.inka3d.com should be the right thing for you. Inka3d supports joints, also objects parented to joints, and you can easily change the rotate parameters from javascript in your exported scene using the same parameter names as in maya.

Answer (score 0):

If you are no coder, you might try [Verge3D for Maya](https://www.soft8soft.com/verge3d-for-maya-released/). It supports skeletal animation and you can rotate your joints with mouse/touch by using visual scripting (namely the "when dragged" and "set rotate" puzzles).